# Is there a way to use Python to call into an API for a given list of values by using a for loop and calling from a list?

Tags: python

I have made an API Call to a website to gather the current list of values I need. I stored those values in a list (called need for this example). I then have a nested for loop where I need to call that ItemName from need into the url to call specific metrics from another API for that ItemName. When I do so, I receive the following Error:

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "dict") to str

I tried pulling the nested for loop out from the other loop, but I still  receive the aforementioned error.

```
for i in need:
    need = i['ItemName']
    print(need)
    # Assign myURI for looping through need
    for ItemName in need:
        myUri = BASEURI + urllib.parse.quote(
            "APIName?DateFrom=***&DateTo=***&ItemName=" + ItemName,
            safe='?=&%')
```

Comment: What is inside the "ItemName" variable? Also refrain from using uppercase for your variable names

Comment: probably unrelated, but the `need = i['ItemName']` overwrites the original `need` so you may want to rethink your naming.

Comment: but anyway: it's impossible to debug this without a representative sample of your data (the original `need` list).

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of `need` - [mcve].

Comment: So ItemName is pulled pulled from another API call, calling in ["Red Shoes", "Gold Watch", "Blue Jacket"] and can vary based on the source nomenclature. I do not control that list, so I felt it would only cause confusion rather than help. So Next time I pull it,there is potential that the API may return ["Blue Shoes", "Silver Watch", "Red Jacket"], so I need to pull these names and store them for recording purposes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List need is a list of strings? if it is then,
The problem is on concatenation of strings, I think that's wrong to concat Itername like this, you need to iterate through  list's -need- elements e.g need[i] .. If I am not wrong you need something like that??..

```
need = ['ItemName']
for i in need:
    print(i)
    # Assign myURI for looping through need
    #some condition for example
    if( i == 'ItemName'): # or is
        myUri = BASEURI + urllib.parse.quote(
            "APIName?DateFrom=***&DateTo=***&ItemName=" + i,
            safe='?=&%')
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Taking the 2nd For loop out and  just inserting it within the  initial for loop got me results.

Comment: I am glad that I helped you! thumbs up for the answer :)